# Why installing custom python packages using RUN in Dockerfile does not work?

Tags: python, docker, module, dockerfile

I've read the below link for installing custom modules on docker:

- [installing-custom-modules-into-docker-container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40566858/installing-custom-modules-into-docker-container)

but I'm using docker file and I'm trying to install my custom module in `Dockerfile` as follow:

```
RUN python myPythonModule/setup.py install
```

Now when I build docker image it shows that it is installing my custom image. When I try to run the newly build docker image with `docker run` it shows the error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_app.py", line 5, in <module>
    from myPythonModule import rpc
ImportError: No module named myPythonModule
```

I have copied the module to where `Dockerfile` is. How exactly should I install my custom python packages in `docker`?

Comment: google where to install python2.7 packages to

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also use pip to install local packages

```
WORKDIR ./myPythonModule
RUN pip install .
```

Answer (score 1):

Try these

```
RUN cd myPythonModule && python setup.py install
```

or

```
RUN cd myPythonModule && PYTHONPATH=. python setup.py install
```